# How to map through data that contains empty values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to map through data to display info such as: date, weekday, name, price and some images. Each object contains some of the same info, but each object has a different number of images or is missing a value in a few spots.

I can display the data on the page properly, but I can't seem to format it because of the different number of images or missing data. There are large white spaces in certain spots where there is missing data (like it is rendering the field that is missing data).

Is this something that can simply be done with CSS? The missing values just are empty strings currently, and am not sure if that is part of what is causing the problem?

I have tried using `:empty` and changing the values to null, with no luck.

Example objects:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "date": "January 1",
  "weekday": "Friday",
  "price": "82¢ + tax",
  "img1": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/danceland-cr.appspot.com/o/1954%2F1954-13-1.jpg?alt=media&token=0afc6a81-cf73-4bd0-bb54-d6ee6eeb59c0" 
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "date": "January 2",
  "weekday": "Saturday",
  "price": "",
  "img1": "" 
]
```

I can see the info being mapped to the page but there are white spaces where the missing `img1` & `price` values would normally go.

Comment: Note that JSON is a text format used "over the wire"; once you get it into React or wherever, it's just plain old JavaScript arrays and objects. See [There is no such thing as a JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: what format you need?

Comment: Also, if you can show us the code you're using to put transform this data into HTML, that would likely help people answer your question.

Comment: can you post the function you used to "display the data on the page"?

Comment: If the return value for undefined values is `null`, an empty string, or `undefined`, then this is a CSS sizing problem. Are you hard coding dimensions? Empty white space does not magically show up unless you're doing something that would explicitly create that space

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make `null` value which contains an empty string(`''`) then you can achieve with `map()` method.

```js
     const array = [{
        "id": 1,
        "date": "January 1",
        "weekday": "Friday",
        "price": "82¢ + tax",
        "img1": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/danceland-cr.appspot.com/o/1954%2F1954-13-1.jpg?alt=media&token=0afc6a81-cf73-4bd0-bb54-d6ee6eeb59c0"
}, {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "January 2",
        "weekday": "Saturday",
        "price": "",
        "img1": ""
}]

const result = array.map((r) => {
        const obj = {
                id: r.id,
                date: r.date,
                weekday: r.weekday,
                price: r.price || null,
                img1: r.img1 || null
        };
        return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to loop through the objects and reducer to replace the empty ones by a null.

```
const objArr = [{
  val1: 'Metallica',
  val2: '',
  val3: 'Iron Maiden',
  val4: '',
  val5: 'Sepultura',
},
{
  val1: 'Parkway Drive',
  val2: '',
  val3: 'Blind Guardian',
  val4: '',
  val5: 'UDO',
}];



objArr.map(obj => 
Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {acc[key] = obj[key] === '' ? null : 
obj[key]; return acc; }, {}) )

output: 
[
  {
    val1: 'Metallica',
    val2: null,
    val3: 'Iron Maiden',
    val4: null,
    val5: 'Sepultura'
  },
  {
    val1: 'Parkway Drive',
    val2: null,
    val3: 'Blind Guardian',
    val4: null,
    val5: 'UDO'
  }
]
```